# Are XMPP server implementations of binding not following the standard?

Tags: binding, xmpp, standards

I recently tried binding based on RFC 6120 (9.1.3 pg 132) with:

```
<iq id='tn281v37' type='set'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/></iq>
```

I would get a response of 'not well formed':

```
<stream:error xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'><not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
```

It took a few days to find out it needed xmlns='jabber:client' :

```
<iq id='tn281v37' type='set' xmlns='jabber:client'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/></iq>
```

It doesn't look like RFC 6120 has been superseded and every example of binding I find on the web doesn't have it. Is this due to implementation of the server? At the time I was binding to chinwag.im

Comment: It sure would have been helpful if you had included what you send, or even the fall XMPP exchange between client u d server. But with the information you provided, I assume that you are missing a proper XML namespace declaration in the stream open tag you send.

Comment: I thought I had just missed pasting it in...but when I just edited to add back what I sent...It is there but not being displayed...will try to get it to display

Comment: Yes, I had said that I found out I needed the xmlns after a few days. The question was asking why the namespace was not listed in RFC 6120. Also 3 or 4 example from books and the web did not show it. Where is it specified is it required?

Comment: As I wrote, it's in the stream open tag. See RFC 6120 § 4.2. You may also want to refresh your knowledge on XML namespace handling in the XML spec. Since XML is an important building block of XMPP, knowing XML is important.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the error again and updated the question. The stream opening did use the namespace as shown in section 6.2 (pg 23), and the server responded with open id and new features. I agree that a careful reading of section 6.1 says every level 1 iq needs a namespace of xmlns='jabber:client'. But why does the spec show an example of binding, in section 9.1.3 on page 132 not showing a namespace after the type='set' ?

Comment: You seem to be confusing § 6 with § 4 of the RFC. Again, the spec shows the binding without `xmlns='jabber:client'`, because the namespace as already declared in the stream open tag. And by XML namespacing rules, the namespaces is inherited by child elements. I still don't see the full exchange between client and server, and I am not sure if this is maybe an XMPP connection over a WebSocket transport (your nickname may suggests that). Hence I am unfortunately not able to help you any further. You may want to try to debug the server to determine the origin of the not-well-formed error.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Yes I am opening the stream both before and after the authentication with jabber:socket and this is why jabber:client is not the default if left blank (like the spec shows). I tried using jabber:client as the namespace when opening the stream in the socket but is failed and seemed to need the socket namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a misunderstanding of how XML namespaces work. In one of your comments you suggested that you are using a namespace of `jabber:socket`, but this is not a namespace that is defined anywhere in the XMPP specs and I could not find any reference to it online. Instead, you want to use `jabber:client` (or `jabber:server` if this were a server-to-server connection). A quick overview of XML namespaces is below:

All XML elements have a "name", this name is made of two parts: the local name and the namespace. The namespace is defined using an `xmlns` attribute, for example the following are *different* elements, they do not have the same name:

```xml
<iq xmlns="jabber:client"/>
<iq xmlns="jabber:server"/>
```

Namespaces declared using an xmlns attribute are inherited by their child elements (unless that element has its own xmlns attribute), therefore in the following:

```xml
<session xmlns="jabber:client">
<iq/>
<foo xmlns="bar"/>
</session>
```

Both the "session" element and the "iq" elements have the namespace "jabber:client" but "foo" has the namespace "bar".

There is also another way to declare a namespace: using a prefix. Prefixes are declared with an "xmlns:prefix" attribute (where "prefix" is the name of the prefix). The list of prefixes is inherited by child elements and don't need to be redeclared, and the namespace defined by the prefix only applies to elements that start with "prefix:". For example:

```xml
<stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client"
               xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
<iq/>
<stream:error></stream:error>
</stream:stream>
```

In the above the "stream" element has the namespace "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams", because it has the "stream:" prefix. The "iq" element on the other hand has the "jabber:client" namespace because it inherits it from the parents "xmlns" attribute. Finally, the "error" element also has the "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" namespace because it uses the "stream:" prefix as well. Notice that it did not have to redeclare the stream prefix because it also inherits a list of prefixes from its parent elements, so just applying the prefix without re-defining it is okay.

It's impossible to tell from the level of detail you provided, but chances are you need to add `xmlns="jabber:client"` to your root element. If you don't have a root element to add it to (ie. when you're using the websocket protocol that sends lot of separate XML documents instead of one long stream), you will have to apply it separately to the root element in every frame you send.

Comment: Thanks. It appears my primary difference between the spec examples and my code, is that I use websockets, and that appears to require redeclaring the namespace every stanza.   
   After searching extensively in the literature and web, I also was unable to find the jabber:socket namespace, but was able to use the jabber:client namespace instead.